# App widget on Android default Lockscreen?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I just want to know whether is it possible to add widget to our Android Lock screen. Actually by selecting widget options in menu in home screen, we add our own or default widgets to home screen. Is it possible to add the following widgets to our lock screen. Is it possible....?
 I have gone through many sites regarding lock screens, but i didn't got the correct information. They gave information related to customized lock screens.

[image: Default Lockscreen]

As per the image, the main thing what i want is as like time & date, can we display our own widget. 
I don't want any customized or our own created lock screen. can we add widgets to default lock screen given by android...?

Waiting for reply, Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Android supports lockscreen widgets in Android 4.2+. The screenshot in your question shows a device running a very old version of Android(I'm not exactly sure which), so it will not work on that.